# What is the meaning of the values returned from trader_bbands()?

Tags: php, trading

I am using the trader [library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php) of PHP.

I use the **`trader_bbands()`** function

```
$bBand = trader_bbands( $NumberArray,
                        25,
                        TRADER_REAL_MIN,
                        TRADER_REAL_MIN,
                        TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA
                        );
```

It returns three arrays.

```
$bBand[0]; // upper-edge of the Bollinger Band           ( an upline )
$bBand[1]; //  central line the Bollinger Bands surround ( a moving average )
$bBand[2]; // lower-edge of the Bollinger Band           ( a downline )
```

My original `$NumberArray` values are all around `2000.0`

`$bBand[1]` is simple moving average so, it returns the numbers around 2000.

However `$bBand[0]` and `$bBand[2]` return values
like this below (example cited from `var_dump()` )

```
  double(3.1325286910105E+38)
  [105] =>
  double(3.1907365920756E+38)
  [106] =>
  double(3.1907365920756E+38)
  [107] =>
  double(3.1740850650235E+38)
  [108] =>
  double(3.1498571396175E+38)
```

**Q1:** What does this array mean?

What I expect from Bollinger Band is array around 2000 + α, or 2000 - α though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A1:**
1. Review the php-library documentation on `trader_bbands()`, as a first step.
2. Publish **`MCVE`**-altogether-with-a-**`DataSET`** to allow validation against a common `DataSET`
3. Compare reference implementations to prove { PASS | FAIL }-status of [**`Trader`** php-library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php) implementation.

> **Ad Step 1.:**
> `array trader_bbands ( array $real [, integer $timePeriod [, float $nbDevUp [, float $nbDevDn [, integer $mAType ]]]] )`

Let's agree to set **`$nbDevUp = 1.0`**, not a technically smallest `float TRADER_REAL_MIN`
Let's agree to set **`$nbDevDn = 1.0`**.

Let's agree to set **`$timePeriod = 7`**

Let's agree to set **`$real`**

```
$real = array(
               0 => 2000.0,
               1 => 2001.0,
               2 => 2002.0,
               3 => 2003.0,
               4 => 2004.0,
               5 => 2005.0,
               6 => 2006.0,
               );
```

### Expectations:

The **`.std()`-sigma**-related values ought get into a fair fashion, independently of not knowing all implementation details about the [**`Trader`** php-library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php) model of `trader_bbands()` calculus, particularly in the **`TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA`** mode, missing the exponential-weighting details used inside their model.
[image]
**Nevertheless**

**A)** There ought be sure all differences
between `$bBand[0][i] - $bBand[1][i]` == `$bBand[1][i] - $bBand[2][i]` to be **== `2.0`**

**B)** There ought be a value of what value of the **exponent** was used in `.ewma()`-method documented somewhere in [**`Trader`** php-library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php).

Well, sure, without such value, one may resort to a brute-force reverse search for a matching value used, but it may be a rather inefficient method to prove the **`$bBand[1]`** values are calculated in [**`Trader`** php-library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.trader.php) in a manner compatible to the common Quant-practice to use
 `ewmaEXP = 2.0 / ( timePeriod + 1 )`.

Comment: Thanks quite a precise answer, I learn more with your help. thanks very much.

Comment: can anybody that understands the answer tell it in a way mortals can understand? thank you!

Comment: nevermind: specifying nbDevUp and nbDevDn results in the expected behavior

Comment: this is very hard to understand