# How to calculate bollinger bands from array in php

Tags: php

I want to calculate bollinger bands using php with my array of data.

I have tried using `trader_bbands` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-bbands.php) but I don't understand the parameter that I should put in especially the `$nbDevUp`, `$nbDecDn`, and `$mAType`.  Then I wondered how to calculate it manually using php, maybe using queue to calculate the middle band or something?

Can anyone help me to understand `trader_bbands`?  I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866649/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-values-returned-from-trader-bbands) but it asks about the return value not the parameter of it.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866649/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-values-returned-from-trader-bbands